# RestyGWT Polymorphic Encode/Decode issues when using an interface instead of an abstract class

Tags: json, gwt, resty-gwt

According to RestyGWT [documentation](http://restygwt.fusesource.org/documentation/restygwt-user-guide.html#_code__JsonSubTypes__code__Example) one must use an abstract super class for this to work, for instance, given:

```
@JsonSubTypes(@Type(value=PersonImpl.class, name="PersonImpl"))
@JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.NAME, include=As.PROPERTY, property="@class")
public abstract class Person{
    public abstract String getName();
    public abstract void setName(String name);
}

@JsonTypeName("PersonImpl")
public class PersonImpl extends Person{
    private String name;

    @Override
    public final String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    @Override
    public final void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

If I use the defined encoder/decoder this would work:

```
Person personInstance = new PersonImpl();
personInstance.setName("TestName");

PersonCodec codec = GWT.create(PersonCodec.class);
JSONValue json = codec.encode(personInstance);
```

Im trying to do something quite similar but with a small difference, that is, instead of **Person** being an abstract class I want it to be an Interface:

```
@JsonSubTypes(@Type(value=PersonImpl.class, name="PersonImpl"))
@JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.NAME, include=As.PROPERTY, property="@class")
public interface Person{
    public String getName();
    public void setName(String name);
}
```

For some reason this doesn't seem to work, as soon as I do that I start getting Errors when the JsonEncoderDecoder is generated. Has someone been able to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: I require Person to be a an interface for unit testing convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not define your interface and make your abstract class implement it?